Looking for general advice for finding collection of evenly spaced vectors as determined by absolute cosine similarity
I have a problem where I'm trying to find a collection of $N$ unit vectors, $V = \left\{ \hat{v}_1,\hat{v}_2,...,\hat{v}_N\right\}$, on the half-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that such for $\hat{v}_i=(x_i,y_i,z_i)\in V\implies0\leq z_i \leq 1$. I have the conditions that for any two vectors $\hat{v}_i$ and $\hat{v}_j$ their absolute dot product is a constant and no two vectors are the same, i.e. $|\hat{v}_i \cdot \hat{v}_j| = c$ and $\hat{v}_i \neq \hat{v}_j$ for all $i\neq j$.
I know I could set up a big system of nonlinear equations and attempt to solve them, but that approach seems too untenable. I've already found a solution when $N=4$, but I was only able to arrive at it by making the assumption that the azimuthal angles of the vectors were evenly spaced around the $z$-axis. I chose to set them as $\phi_1 = 0$, $\phi_2 = \pi/2$, $\phi_3 = \pi$, and $\phi_4 = 3\pi/2$. With this, I was able to write the collection of vectors as:
\begin{align*}
\hat{v}_1 &= (\sin(\theta_1)\cos(\phi_1),\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\phi_1),\cos(\theta_1)) = (\sin(\theta_1),0,\cos(\theta_1))\\
\hat{v}_2 &= (\sin(\theta_2)\cos(\phi_2),\sin(\theta_2)\sin(\phi_2),\cos(\theta_2))=(0,\sin(\theta_2),\cos(\theta_2))\\
\hat{v}_3 &= (\sin(\theta_3)\cos(\phi_3),\sin(\theta_3)\sin(\phi_3),\cos(\theta_3)) = (-\sin(\theta_3),0,\cos(\theta_3))\\
\hat{v}_4 &= (\sin(\theta_4)\cos(\phi_4),\sin(\theta_4)\sin(\phi_4),\cos(\theta_4)) = (0,-\sin(\theta_4),\cos(\theta_4))
\end{align*}
The next assumption I made was that $\beta:=\theta_1=\theta_2=\theta_3=\theta_4$, giving the equations
\begin{align*}
\hat{v}_1 &= \left(\phantom{-}\sin(\beta),\phantom{-si}0\phantom{n()},\cos(\beta)\right)\\
\hat{v}_2 &= \left(\phantom{-si}0\phantom{n()},\phantom{-}\sin(\beta),\cos(\beta)\right)\\
\hat{v}_3 &= \left(-\sin(\beta),\phantom{-si}0\phantom{n()},\cos(\beta)\right)\\
\hat{v}_4 &= \left(\phantom{-si}0\phantom{n()},-\sin(\beta),\cos(\beta)\right)
\end{align*}
A brute force method would have me minimize the function
\begin{equation}
f(\beta) = \sum_{i\neq j} |\hat{v}_i \cdot \hat{v}_j| = 4|\cos^2(\beta)| + 2|\cos^2(\beta)-\sin^2(\beta)| 
\end{equation}
however, due to all "distances" needing to be the same we can merely try to solve
\begin{equation}
|\hat{v}_1 \cdot \hat{v}_2| = |\cos^2(\beta)| = |\cos^2(\beta)-\sin^2(\beta)| = |\hat{v}_1 \cdot \hat{v}_3|
\end{equation}
for $0$. We can square both sides to get
\begin{align*}
\cos^4(\beta) &= \cos^4(\beta)-2\cos^2(\beta)\sin^2(\beta) + \sin^4(\beta)\\
&\implies 2\cos^2(\beta)\sin^2(\beta) = \sin^4(\beta)\\
&\implies 2\cos^2(\beta) = \sin^2(\beta)\\
&\implies 2\cos^2(\beta) = 1-cos^2(\beta)\\
&\implies \cos^2(\beta) = \frac{1}{3}\\
&\implies \beta = \arccos\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\right)\\
\end{align*}
Getting this result is all well and good, however, I feel a bit uncomfortable starting out with the assumptions without knowing an underlying principle that justifies that as my starting point. Moreover, I'd like this optimization to be able to have a general approach to it. I've tried seeing if there's any connection between this kind of problem and the construction of polyhedra under certain symmetry constraints, but that kind of 3D Euclidean geometry I am not well versed. I'd like to know if anyone has an idea as to how this problem could be set up and possibly how to begin solving it.
